# Grails scaffolding with embedded

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

With those domain class

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar
    static embedded = [ 'bar' ] 
}


class Bar {
    String name
}
```

And a controller

```
class FooController {
    static scaffold = Foo
}
```

I got a error whe accessing /foo/create

```
java.lang.nullpointerexception cannot get property 'name' on null object
```

I see that there's a bug in open for that http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSCAFFOLD-28

As there is no planned fix version for now, is there any workaround?

Comment: Here's a great workaround that works for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902093/how-can-i-use-embedded-gorm-classes-in-grails

Answer (score 0):

this may be help-full to you @ https://github.com/bhannat2012/grails-employee-address-emb